# Flutter how to update ListView in FutureBuilder

Tags: firebase, listview, flutter, location

I want to update my listview which is created in futurebuilder, I want to update this on slider change

```
FlutterSlider(
          values: [150],
          min: 0,
          max: 150,

          onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
            radius = upperValue;
            users.clear();
            fut = _gdb.getUsersInRadius(radius);
          },
        ),
```

and code of futurebuilder and list view

```
Expanded(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: fut,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              if(!snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                return Center(
                    child: Text("No users"));
                   }else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                return SpinKitWave(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor);
              }
              return StreamBuilder(
                stream: snapshot.data,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                  if(!snapshot.hasData){
                    return Center(
                        child: SpinKitWave(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ));
                       }else{
                         print(snapshot.data.length);
                         users.addAll(snapshot.data);
                         return ListView.builder(
                             controller: _scrollController ,
                             itemCount: users.length,
                             itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index){

                                 return GestureDetector(
                                   onTap: (){
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/userWidget', arguments: users[index]);
                                   },
                                   child: Card(
                                     child: Column(
                                       children: [
                                         Text(users[index].data['username']),
                                         FutureBuilder(
                                           future: FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('profilepics').child('${users[index].documentID}.jpg').getDownloadURL(),
                                           builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                                             if(!snapshot.hasData){
                                               return CircleAvatar();
                                             }
                                             return CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data) ,) ;//.network(snapshot.data)
                                           },
                                         ),
                                         Text(users[index].data['city'] == null ? "No city" : users[index].data['city'] )
                                       ],
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 );
                             });
                       }
                     },
                   );
                 },
               ),
             )
```

When user will change value of slider new users nearby will be loaded to listview and old will be deleted
Users are downloaded from Firestore using Geoflutterfire,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call `setState` when doing `fut = _gdb.getUsersInRadius(radius);`

About the slider part

```
FlutterSlider(
          values: [sliderValue], // initialize it with 150
          min: 0,
          max: 150,

      onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
        radius = upperValue;
        users.clear();
        setState(){(){
            sliderValue = upperValue; // update it like this.
            fut = _gdb.getUsersInRadius(radius);
        }}


      },
    ),
```

Comment: almost works but now I have problem with slider, when I'm trying to change value bar is going to start position and value is not changing

Comment: Can you provide the code for the whole screen here if possible? I think for some reason that FlutterSlider is rebuilding

Comment: Does the slider go to 150 value or 0 value?

Comment: Slider is going to 150 on every move

Comment: I see the Slider is rebuilding. Instead of using 150 directly in Slider's values, use a variable, like currentSliderValue = 150; And in onDragging,  inside the setState method use currentSliderValue = upperValue; Let me know if it works

Comment: I don't understand what you mean could you give more details?

Comment: Updated the answer. please have a look